# why template not working in reset password loopback

Tags: node.js, express, loopbackjs

i m just confuse why template not working in reset password function

```
  user.on('resetPasswordRequest', function(info) {
   var url = 'http://' + config.host + ':' + config.port + '/reset-password';
   var html = 'Click <a href="' + url + '?access_token=' +
    info.accessToken.id + '">here</a> to reset your password';
     user.app.models.Email.send({
          to: info.email,
          from: info.email,
          subject: 'Password reset',
          html: html
    }, function(err) {
       if (err) return console.log('> error sending password reset email');
      console.log('> sending password reset email to:', info.email);
   });
 });
```

above code is working fine but if i use template intead of html then i got empty template in email for eg like below

```
    user.app.models.Email.send({
          to: info.email,
          from: info.email,
          subject: 'Password reset',
         template: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../server/views/verify.ejs'),
    }, function(err) {
       if (err) return console.log('> error sending password reset email');
      console.log('> sending password reset email to:', info.email);
   });
```

if i use this same template in user.verify method it work there  then why it not working here
is there any other alternative to provide template in password reset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello rocky you can try something like this

```
var ejs = require("ejs");

var token = info.accessToken.id;
var pathreset= path.resolve(__dirname, '../../server/views/resetpassword1.ejs');

ejs.renderFile(pathreset, { username: info.user.username, token:token }, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
                console.log(err);
         } else {

             var options={
                to: info.email,
                from: credentials.user,
                subject: 'Password reset',
                html:data
                }

             User.app.models.Email.send(options, function(err) {
                    if (err) return console.log('> error sending password reset email');
                     console.log('> sending password reset email to:', info.email);
             });
```

hope this will help you as well other

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually using **html** instead of **template** attribute, and creating a template with loopback, so your code would looks like:

```
 var loopback = require('loopback');
 var render = loopback.template(path.join(__dirname, '../../server/views/verify.ejs'));
 var html = render(
    // only if you need to map some fields in your .ejs file
    {
            firstName: firstname,
            lastName: lastname,
            link: confirmLink
    }
);

    user.app.models.Email.send({
              to: info.email,
              from: info.email,
              subject: 'Password reset',
              text: html,
              html: html
        }, function(err) {
           if (err) return console.log('> error sending password reset email');
          console.log('> sending password reset email to:', info.email);
       });
```